# Can you unlock a file with lockf from another process?

Tags: c, unix, locking, lockfile

If I set a lock in process A that has two child processes with :

`int a = lockf(fic2, F_LOCK, 0);`

can I unlock it in process B with :

`int b = lockf(fic2, F_ULOCK, 0);`

It seems unlocking from B doesn't release the lock from A.

Any explanation would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: *Any explanation would be appreciated,*  What good is a lock that someone else can unlock?  When you lock your car or your house, do you then distribute spare keys to everyone you see?

Comment: This is supposed to be a advisory-lock, any process can bypass the lock. So now you tell me what good is a lock that doesn't lock anything but that can't be unlocked by whomever. Do you leave your door open with a lock on it ? What good does allowing any process to access the file but not any process to unlock the lock.

Comment: Whether or not it's "advisory" or not is entirely irrelevant.  Allowing someone else to remove it means even someone who wants to follow the restrictions ***can't***.  **Do you lock your bathroom stall in a public bathroom?  If only to use the "advisory" features of that "lock" to prevent strangers from thinking the stall is not in use?**  I'm guessing you wouldn't appreciate some third party just making that lock disappear at just the wrong time...

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I prefer my mutexes to be unlockable by anybody, so I can hand off locks from one process to another.

Comment: @Joshua I prefer my **mutexes** to actually implement **MUT**ual **EX**clusion.  If I want something to pass to another process, I'll use something meant for that, like a semaphore.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I recall too many cases of lightweight locks stopping working when async/await appeared because they checked whether the unlocking thread was the locking thread. Same principle applies. Right now, I can't mix async/await with sqlite because flock is dumb. We note that APIs of this age usually turn out to mean thread when they say process.